# mysql join return nothing if does not have data

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function getUserList() {
        $sql = "SELECT users.id, users.name, about.profile_img, user_game_info.at_game, SUM(user_img.likes) AS likes FROM users 
                JOIN about ON users.id = about.uid
                JOIN user_game_info ON about.uid = user_game_info.uid
                INNER JOIN user_img ON user_game_info.uid = user_img.uid";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($query->rowCount()) {
            $userList = $query->fetchAll();
            return $userList;
        }
        return false;       
    }
```

It works, but if my user_img has no uid, i want to show likes count 0.
This query returns only if img_user has uid, if does not have it didn' t return anything.

[image]

[image]

This is only for user_img. For example, that query must be return 0 for uid 3. Because user_img has no uid = 3. But it does not return any data for uid 3.

Comment: Use an `outer join` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OK I have updated the SQL try again:**

You need left join:

```
$sql = '
SELECT u.id, u.name, a.profile_img, ugi.at_game, SUM(ifnull(i.likes,0)) AS likes 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN about a ON u.id = a.uid
LEFT JOIN user_game_info ugi ON u.id = ugi.uid
LEFT JOIN user_img i ON u.id = i.uid
GROUP BY 1';
```

Comment: it returns only first row. if i delete user_img, it returns all data

Comment: I m not sure your table structure and relationship of the tables. Try all LEFT Join and see what happens. By the way, try: http://topnew.net/sidu might be easier for you to manage mysql

Comment: it seems sum has problem. i tried with i.likes AS likes, it returned.

Comment: also i added; GROUP BY u.id and it works, thanks for helping